# How to close a JFrame on a class that implements ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I need to close a specific JFrame with another class that implements ActionListener

```
public class EditStudent extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EditStudent frame = new EditStudent();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

I will use this class to a JButton on that JFrame. (It's like a controller to a JButton)

```
public class EditFileController implements ActionListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private JButton btnEdit = new JButton();

    public EditFileController(JButton btnEdit) {
        super();
        EditStudent.btnEdit = btnEdit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take note that I will use that class to a JButton on that specific JFrame

Comment: What have you tried?  Please see [ask].

Comment: Every searchable method. I've been searching for at least 5 hrs.

Comment: While I'm impressed that you've stayed at it for 5 hours, it would help if you could post something you've tried that ended up failing, along with your understanding of what the code is (or should be) doing.  Then we can clear up the root of the issue, which is likely a misunderstanding, rather than just handing you a solution.

Comment: I tried using EditStudent frame = new EditStudent();
frame.setVisible(false);
but it just ending up creating new JFrame and setting its vsibility to false.
What I wanted to happen is to close the current JFrame in which when you click a JButton, controlled by a different class that implements ActionListener, will close.

Comment: Well, then you have to pass the current `JFrame` to the controller, where you close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every searchable method. I've been searching for at least 5 hrs.

Well start with the basics of how to write an ActionListener. The code you posted doesn't even implement the `actionPerformed(...)` method so it won't even compile.

Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. Maybe start with the section on `How to Use Lists`. The `ListDemo` code shows how to use an inner class to define an ActionListener.

Your controller class makes no sense to me. You appear to be making it to complicated. For example why would you pass the button as a parameter but also make a new instance of the button in the class.

An ActionListener does NOT to define the button or have it passed as a parameter.

All you need to do is create the button where you add all other components to the frame. Then you add the ActionListener to your button.

Then the the basic code in your ActionListener would be:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(event.getSource());
window.dispose();
```

Once you get that working and understand the basic concepts you may want to check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) which presents a simple API to create reusable code that can be used for any frame.

Comment: I just posted the code to assume that I am implementing an ActionListener to a class, that without a doubt, am using an actionPerformed. Tho, I am not aware how to use that method Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(event.getSource());

Comment: Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(EditStudent.btnEdit);
       window.dispose();

Comment: Thank you, it is now closing when I click the JButton.

Comment: @KennethArias, Nooooo! That is NOT what I suggested. There is no need for you to reference "EditStudent.btnEdit". That is completely wrong. You were give two simple lines of code that can be used in the actionPerformed() method of your ActionListener. *I just posted the code to assume* - We can't "assume" anything. Your exact code should be posted so we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: There is a specific reason why I need to reference it. I am creating a CRUD with the use of MVC. I am referencing it in another class because it was supposed to be a controller.
And the main JFrame is just a view or just simply a GUI.

Comment: It doesn't matter what class you reference it in. The ActionEvent contains the button that was clicked. What part of the two lines of code is not clear?